# Flutter Firebase AppCheck failure

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-storage, firebase-app-check

**E/flutter (28083): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: [firebase_storage/unauthenticated] User is unauthenticated. Authenticate and try again.
E/flutter (28083): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: [firebase_storage/unauthenticated] User is unauthenticated. Authenticate and try again.
E/StorageException(28083): {  "error": {    "code": 401,    "message": "Firebase App Check token is invalid."  }}
E/StorageException(28083): java.io.IOException: {  "error": {    "code": 401,    "message": "Firebase App Check token is invalid."  }}**

I get this errors when i try to get images from Firebase Storage.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: any solution for this ? i have the same error message